# Concatenate one .data and one .bss string together in x86_64 assembly

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, nasm, x86-64

I am writing a program, that asks for you name, and then prints it out like so:

```
<name> is your name?
```

Here is my current code:

```
section .data
    promptText: db "What is your name: ", 0
    promptTextLength: equ $ - promptText
    secondText: db " is your name?", 0

section .bss
    name resb 15

section .text:
    global _start

_start:

    ; Print prompt message
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, promptText
    mov rdx, promptTextLength
    syscall

    ; Get name
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdi, 0
    mov rsi, name
    mov rdx, 15
    syscall

    ; Somehow concatenate "name" and "secondText"

    ; Print second message
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, nameAndSecondText
    mov rdx, nameAndSecondTextLength
    syscall

    ; Exit 0
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

So, pretty much add `name` and  `secondText`, then print them to to terminal.

However,

I do not want to just call `SYS_WRITE` twice, to print both strings, I need to combine `name` and `secondText` into their own variable.

Thanks!

P.S sorry if i am using the wrong terminology, I am used to higher level languages, like Python, C, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the terminating NUL of a string since you don't use functions that check for this character.

Delete the colon in `section .text:`. Then you can debug the program with GDB.

I suggest to append `secondText` directly to the entered name. For this you have to reserve more space for the variable `name`. SYS_READ does not notice this, so the space remains blank after the call to SYS_READ.

```
section .data
    promptText:         db "What is your name: "
    promptTextLength:   equ $ - promptText
    secondText:         db " is your name?", 10
    secondTextLength:   equ $ - secondText

section .bss
    name resb 15 + secondTextLength ; Space for input and appended string

section .text
global _start

_start:

    ; Print prompt message
    mov rax, 1                  ; SYS_WRITE - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html
    mov rdi, 1                  ; fd = STDOUT
    mov rsi, promptText         ; *buf
    mov rdx, promptTextLength   ; Count of bytes to write
    syscall                     ; Call Linux

    ; Get name
    mov rax, 0                  ; SYS_READ - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html
    mov rdi, 0                  ; fd = STDIN
    mov rsi, name               ; *buf
    mov rdx, 15                 ; Max count of bytes to read
    syscall                     ; Call Linux - return EAX = number of bytes read
    dec rax                     ; number of bytes read without ENTER

    ; Append secondText
    mov rsi, secondText         ; *source
    mov rdi, name               ; *dest
    add rdi, rax                ; Set pointer one byte behind the real name
    mov rcx, secondTextLength   ; Count of bytes to copy
    lea rbx, [rax + rcx]        ; Save the total length of the string
    rep movsb                   ; Copy RCX bytes from [RSI] to [RDI]

    ; Print name (input + second message)
    mov rax, 1                  ; SYS_WRITE - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html
    mov rdi, 1                  ; fd = STDOUT
    mov rsi, name               ; *buf
    mov rdx, rbx                ; Count of bytes to write (RBX was saved above)
    syscall                     ; Call Linux

    ; Exit (0)
    mov rax, 60                 ; SYS_EXIT
    mov rdi, 0                  ; Exitcode
    syscall                     ; Call Linux / no return
```